# Strategy to map multiple lookup tables with system tables?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a bunch of lookup tables:

```
Religion  
Country  
City  
nationality  
Currency
```

etc... approx 80-100 lookup tables.

Now I have system tables where i am centralizing all the fields and values so i can ID all fields, centralize them for reporting and add multi-language to my lookups. So these are tables like:

```
Form (all forms on system)  
Field (all fields on system)  
Value (all values for all fields on system)  
Form_Field_value (mapping them together)  
Translation (maps value and field to multi language)
```

but the question is how to get all the 80-100 tables data into these Field / Value tables? So it will be like this:

```
Field table:
id 1 Natioality  
id 2 Country   
1d 3 city  
...

Value table
1d 1 american   
id 2 chinese  
id 3 rusian  
...

field_value  
id 1, field_id1, value_id1  
id 2, field_id1, value_id2  
id 3, field_id1, value_id3  
...
```

Ofcourse i can manually do it but then it defeats the purpose of having those lookup tables. So ideal is to keep these tables in sync. next question is which tables to use for user forms? The lookup tables or the `form_fields` table?

Answer (score 1):

`union select` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: But union doesnt solve the issue of how to link these tables. i mean if i declare city to be field ID 45 and chicago tobe value id 34. There are 30 different forms that use city field on my site and stored across say 20 different tables. i want all of them to have the same IDs so i can do anaytics in backend.